# Excessive disk I/O when using VSCode remote SSH for Next.js development

Tags: node.js, next.js, development-environment, disk-io, vscode-remote-ssh

I'm encountering an issue where Node.js processes are consuming excessive disk I/O when I'm using Visual Studio Code (VSCode) with Remote SSH to develop Next.js applications on a cloud server. This high disk I/O activity seems to be related to file monitoring and potentially other VSCode features.

I expect to have a smooth development experience with VSCode Remote SSH for Next.js development, without excessive disk I/O activity impacting performance.